# Proof of the equivalence between two ways of defining ESS

Tags: evolution, theoretical-biology, evolutionary-game-theory

### Background

Two common ways of defining what an Evolutionary Stable Strategy (ESS) are:

**First definition**:
Consider a population composed of populations playing two strategies, $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$.
Let us denote $W(\mathbf{p})$ the average fitness of the
strategy $\mathbf{p}$. A population consisting of individuals playing $\mathbf{p}$ will be an ESS if, whenever a small amount of deviant individuals playing $\mathbf{q}$, the old type $\mathbf{p}$ fares batter than the newcomers $\mathbf{q}$. This means that for all
$\mathbf{p}\neq \mathbf{q}$,
\begin{equation}
  W(\mathbf{p}) > W (\mathbf{q})
\end{equation}

**Second definition**: $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})$ is the payoff for $\mathbf{p}$-strategist against a $\mathbf{q}$-strategist. The strategy $\mathbf{p}$ is an ESS if and only if the following conditions are satisfied:

1. $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p})\geq E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p}) \quad \forall
     \mathbf{q}$
2. If $\mathbf{q}\neq \mathbf{p}$ and $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p}) = E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})$, then
   $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})> E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{q})$

### Question (shorter version)

The above two ways of defining what an ESS should be equivalent. How can I prove such an equivalence? Alternatively, do you know of a book (or a paper) that has this proof?

### Question (longer version)

I understand that the first definition implies the second. According to the first definition:
\begin{align*}
   W(\mathbf{p}) - W (\mathbf{q}) &>0\\
   (1-\epsilon) [E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p}) - E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})]
   + \epsilon [E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}) - E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{q})] &>0
 \end{align*}
where $\epsilon$ is frequency of individuals playing $\mathbf{q}$. Since $0<\epsilon<1$, if the above inequality is true, the conditions 1 and 2 in the second definition must be true. The part that I find less clear is how the second definition implies the first definition. More specifically, that if $\mathbf{p}$ is a strict Nash equilibrium (i.e., $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p})> E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})$), then $W(\mathbf{p}) > W (\mathbf{q})$.

Comment: Aren't these definitions applicable to different models of evolution?  It seems like the first is applicable in a case where each strategy has, regardless of the other strategies, a known distribution of payoffs.  The second seems to have a payoff which is dependent not only on the strategy but also on the other players' strategy.  If they are different models, I am not sure what it means to be equivalent.

Comment: @Hans The equivalence between these defs is mentioned in a few textbooks, such as p.232 of Gintis *Game Theory Evolving* and on p. 63 of Hofbauer & Sigmund's *Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that if $\mathbf{p}$ is a strict Nash equilibrium, $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p})> E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})$, then $W(\mathbf{p}) > W (\mathbf{q})$ for some sufficiently small $\epsilon$. When $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}) \geq E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{q})$, $\mathbf{p}$ clearly dominates $\mathbf{q}$.The less obvious case is when $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}) < E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{q})$.

Since $E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p}) - E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})>0$, there should be a strictly positive number $k$ such that
$$k[E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p}) - E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})]+ E(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}) - E(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{q})>0$$
is true. Whatever this number is, we can write $k$ as $(1-\epsilon)/\epsilon$ for $0<\epsilon<1$. Substituting this into the equation above gives us the desired result.